# Basic Batch File Doesn't Work

Tags: batch-file

As far as I can tell this is perfectly valid batch-file code, just a very simple echo command, but everytime I run it, it does nothing - it doesn't echo the text to any window at all.

```
@echo off
ECHO Hello World
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here? It works fine in a CMD window, so my best guess is that maybe a batch file requires a bit more code to get working? Other than that, not a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a `PAUSE` at the end, the command window (if you run the .bat file directly) will briefly flash and then disappear, because the script finishes running and closes the command window. If you run through Command Prompt, there isn't the issue, as you've mentioned above.

To mitigate the issue, `PAUSE` the window once you've finished `ECHO`-ing:

```
@echo off
ECHO Hello World
PAUSE
```

Comment: So does this mean that everytime I want to use an echo in a batch file, I need to add the pause command? Only scripts that I saw online never used a PAUSE command, so I assumed one wasn't needed.

Comment: `Pause` simply causes the batch to pause at that point.  Without it, the batch finishes and the window closes before you have a chance to read the echos or any other output.  Just put one `Pause` at the end of the batch file.

Comment: @Hashim As Hand-E-Food points out above, only one `PAUSE` is needed, at the end of the script. Otherwise, the batch file runs and closes its window. If you placed a `PAUSE` at the end of _every_ echo statement, the batch file would pause after every one of those echoed statements.